# Terminating loop using stream selector in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, select, blocking, python-multithreading

I've got some code running in a thread to wait for an incoming client connection using a socket:

```
import threading
import socket
import selectors

class Server(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        # instantiate socket
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        # bind the socket
        self.socket.bind(("localhost", 50000))

    def run(self):
        # create selector to interface with OS
        sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

        # register the connection handler for when a client connects
        sel.register(self.socket, selectors.EVENT_READ, self.handle_connection)

        while True:
            events = sel.select()
            for key, _ in events:
                # run the callback
                key.data()

    def handle_connection(self):
        # handle a request on the socket
        data = self._socket.accept()

        # do stuff with data...

    def stop(self):
        # what to do?
        pass
```

This code enters the `while True` loop and calls `sel.select()` which blocks until something is read from `self._socket`, upon which it calls the callback `self.handle_connection` (not relevant to my question). This works nicely, but what I'd also like to be able to do is to break the `while True` loop using the thread's `stop` method, so that my main program loop elsewhere can stop the thread and shut down the server gracefully.

I can't just check a flag like `while self.running:` because `sel.select()` blocks until something is read. I also thought about using the selector's error handling mechanism, but I don't necessarily want to shut down the server just during errors/exceptions.

It seems like I need the selector to read from a second stream which would contain a special command to stop the loop, but this seems overly complicated. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe `timeout` parameter in `select` will help? https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/selectors.html#selectors.BaseSelector.select

Comment: Ah yes, that's it! I added a 1 second timeout and changed the `while True` loop to `while self.server_running`, and made the `stop` method set `self.server_running = False`. As simple as that! Thank you.

Comment: No problem! I'll post an answer so other people could use it, as suggested here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291167/posting-an-answer-after-posting-it-in-comment-that-solved-the-ops-problem/291168#291168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've said that you're ok with using a `while self.flag` instead of `while True`, you may specify a `timeout` parameter, [as explained in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/selectors.html#selectors.BaseSelector.select). Just make sure to check your data before entering the `for key, _ in events:` loop